# How to zoom a webcam in KDE Plasma 5 on openSUSE Tumbleweed?

Tags: opensuse, camera, kde5, zoom

I have a [Schenker XMG U706 notebook](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Schenker-XMG-U706-Clevo-P771DM-Notebook-Review.150989.0.html) which has a [BisonCam NB Pro](http://www.bisontech.com.tw/products.html) cam in it. I remember when having used [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) (What a coincidende in naming! :) under (dual boot) Windows I could zoom in/out the video. Now that I have to use [BigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org/) in FF under Linux my face (in appx. 1 m distance) fills about 1/8 of the video display only and apparently there isn't any option to change this in this virtual classroom  app.

Is there a way to change the zoom level a level below the app and the browser, e.g. in webcam settings of KDE or the OS itself?

Comment: Install qv4l2 third tab contains zoom slider , but im not sure how to save value.

Comment: @GoranTosev Late to my own party since I missed your comment until just a few mins ago. I installed `qv4l2` (1.24.1) now but its third tab _Camera Controls_ just contains _Exposure, Dynamic Framerate_ ☒. Is it _Cropping & Compose Settings_ on its first tab _General Setings_, perhaps? But I can't change anything on the sliders there anyway.

Comment: @GoranTosev Running it with `sudo`: `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.\n
 This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.\n\n 
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb`